# Passing more than 3 items in a reports column link

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a report that is listing students and I want a column to edit a student. I've done so by following this answer:

[How do you add an edit button to each row in a report in Oracle APEX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075550/how-do-you-add-an-edit-button-to-each-row-in-a-report-in-oracle-apex)

However, I can only seem to pass 3 items and there's no option to add more. I took a screenshot to explain more:

[image]

I need to pass 8 values, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly do you require to pass on 8 values? This listing is an interactive report i assume?

Answer (score 3):

Normally, for this you would only pass the Primary Key columns (here looks like #RECORD_NUMBER# only). The page that you send the person to would then load the form based on the primary key lookup only. If multiple users were using this application, you would want the edit form to always retrieve the current values of the database, not what happened to be on the screen when a particular person ran a certain report.

Answer (score 2):

Change the Target type to URL.
Apex will format what to already have into a URL text field which magically appears between Tem3 and Page Checksum. 
All you need to do is to add your new items and values in the appropriate places in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, at least it was useful to my scenario.
I have an IR page, query returns 4 columns, lets say: ID, DESCRIPTION, SOME_NUMBER,SOME_NUMBER2.
ID NUMBER(9), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(30), SOME_NUMBER NUMBER(1), SOME_NUMBER2 NUMBER(3).
What I did was, to setup items this way:
  `P11_ITEM1-->#ID#`
  `P11_ITEM2-->#DESCRIPTION#`
  `P11_ITEM3-->#SOME_NUMBER##SOME_NUMBER2#`

Previous data have been sent to page 11.
In page 11, all items are  display only items.
And P11_ITEM3 actually received two concatenated values.
For example, the calling page has columns SOME_NUMER=4 and SOME_NUMBER2=150
so, in pag1 11, P11_ITEM3 shows 4150
In page 11 I created a Before Footer process (pl/sql expression)
to set up new items, for example P11_N1 as source SUBSTR(P11_ITEM3,1,1)
and item P11_N2 as source SUBSTR(P11_ITEM3,2,3)
So, I had those items with corresponding values from the calling IR page.

The reason I did not pass the primary key only for new lookup access, is because i do not want to stress database performing new queries since all data are already loaded into page items. I've been an oracle DBA for twenty years and I know there is no need to re execute queries if you already have the information somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

These workarounds are not very useful for a product that bills itself as a RAD tool.
Just include a single quoted word in the select statement (Select col1, 'Randomword', col2 from table 1;)
Then define that column as a link and bingo! More items than 3 to select.