# how to add button for each row record in apex5

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created an interactive report in apex5.0 with below select:
SELECT article_code,article_desc,order_date, order_status
FROM table_order
WHERE status in ('SHIP','DELIVER','CANCEL');

I want for each row record to have a button that when click it calls another page.
How to do that??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add an edit button to each row in a report in Oracle APEX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075550/how-do-you-add-an-edit-button-to-each-row-in-a-report-in-oracle-apex)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options.

1. Edit the column and change the type of the column to Link.
2. Create an html link with an href to the page you want.  Choose type display, then turn of escaping special characters in the column properties.

Comment: Thxs, getting the edit link..., is it possible to add a specific type of button to it.?  How to add href in the select statement itself?

Comment: whenever I change the column type from plain text to link and save it, it gets back to plain text..ie I'm not able to save with column type as link , it gets back to Plain text, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Calling another page is declarative, out of the box behaviour, and you'll find such examples in the documentation.

Declarative
http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/editing-interactive-reports-page-designer.htm#GUID-B30458D6-9678-40D4-A477-28EE466ED50A

As link column
http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/editing-interactive-reports-in-component-view.htm#GUID-48AF053F-0E34-40FA-94FE-19C0400AD499

Manual
http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/understanding-url-syntax.htm#HTMDB03019

Using dynamic action http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2015/12/tutorial-include-action-button-in-report.html